# PC boots bootable usb but turns keyboard and mouse off as soon as it gets into the windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, keyboard, mouse

I have already tried booting priority of the usb while disabling legacy usb support, already tried setting csm mode, have all drivers up tp date too, I also tried changing the PCIs to gen 3, but i find it weird since I have already i stalled windows 10 with the same keyboard and mouse.

```
MSI MAG B550 TOMAHAWK 
AMD RYZEN 5 5600X
MSI GAMING X TRIO 3070
Patriot Viper Steel 3733 dont k ow the clk
And a m.2 forgot the name
Bios is E7C91AMS.A40
```

Comment: Windows 7 is well more than a decade old. New boards often do not let Windows 7 be installed. That is likely the issue here. If you need Windows 7, run it in a virtual machine. That works - I have it running that way here.

Comment: W7 does not have the usb 3.x drivers for that motherboard, nor will MSI have any other driver for W7. Agree run it in a VM.

Comment: How come they are offering utility downloads for win7

Comment: Some utilities may work. Drivers for some hardware devices may not work / work properly. It is best, I think, not to try installing it as a real machine on this newer board.

Answer (score 0):

As time goes by and Windows 7 gets farther behind, there is less and less likelihood that new boards / computers will run Windows 7.

Microsoft has asked manufacturers to disallow Windows 7 installations.  At best for this board, some things may work, some will not work or not work properly (particularly basic and important drivers) leaving a less than useful installation.

The computer you have will support virtual machines and I suggest installing Windows 7 as a virtual machine with Hyper-V or VMware Workstation.  Both work.

This will work better than trying to install Windows 7 because of the absence of compliant drivers.

Comment: Sad to hear, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested whether you had keyboard and mouse to start with(In the BIOS/UEFI)?

There can be an issue with Windows 7 and USB3 (Where it works in the BIOS but not in Win7)

See this tutorial http://codeabitwiser.com/2014/03/how-to-install-windows-7-with-only-usb-3-0-ports/  it mentions "The keyboard and mouse worked great in the BIOS, but as soon as the Windows 7 installation media loaded and presented that familiar Language Select screen, I had no cursor or keyboard.".  The tutorial uses the DISM command.

This guy goes through that tutorial here  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgF6FUeKCqQ

Alternatively if you have a USB2.0 port then you could try that!

Or, Gigabyte have a tool https://www.cybernetman.com/kb/article/how-to-slipstream-usb-3-0-drivers-into-windows-7-installation-media    And that would be easier to try than the tutorial that uses DISM.

I actually found en_windows_7_ultimate_with_sp1_x64_dvd_u_677332.iso  was fine for me. But I have heard that you may need to slipstream drivers in or point it to drivers. And that link I mentioned shows how, and that video can help.

There is a part of windows 7 installation where it has a "load driver" option but I see you can't even get to that point with this issue 'cos you are stuck at the very first screen the choose a language screen. So it looks like those methods are the way to go. Your issue looks to be exactly what the tutorial describes.

In my personal experience, I haven't encountered this exact issue, but I encountered something once that looked a bit like that so I did run into some solutions re it, that I have mentioned here.

Comment: Both keyboard and mouse work just fine in bios, and on windows 10 partition, but they go off as soon as i get to the windows 7 installer. I also tried usb on all ports. I got 3.1 and 2.0 usbs.

Comment: @PCnoob that does match what he describes at the link I mention "The keyboard and mouse worked great in the BIOS, but as soon as the Windows 7 installation media loaded and presented that familiar Language Select screen, I had no cursor or keyboard."

Comment: @PCnoob also I vaguely recall a tool to help put USB3 support into Win7. I will see if I can find it. But that method I mention is more manual

Comment: @PCnoob https://www.cybernetman.com/kb/article/how-to-slipstream-usb-3-0-drivers-into-windows-7-installation-media      Gigabyte wrote a tool to so you could try that too

Comment: Thanks for the help! My keyboard and mouse are 2.0 usb but i still tried this tutorial without any luck.

Comment: I tried booting the usb and connecting the keyboard and mouse on the 2.0 ports and the keyboard and mouse still go off as soon as it hits the installation screen. Thank You all for your help I give up on this

Comment: @PCnoob  You have an interesting problem, no need to give up yet.  There can be quick things to try. And it's a very interesting problem. What's the make and model of the computer?  Also, I see something mentioned here https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/fix-usb-mouse-and-keyboard-stop-working-issue-in-windows-7/   You could try look for an option in the BIOS for Legacy USB support,  make sure it's enabled.

Comment: Where can i find the make and model of the computer? And Legacy USB Support was enabled I even disabled it it cuz some other aites said that might be the problem...

Comment: I also changed the pcie to gen 3 in an occasion! Idk if this will help you but the usb where my windows install is only shows up when i enable csm, when i enable Eufi it just doesnt load.

Comment: @PCnoob    i'm not talking about the CSM option that's a different legacy option..  But within legacy BIOS(so when CSM is enabled), sometimes there's an option for legacy USB support!  https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tsIHrpDHw5k/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: Ooh yeah the one that says legacy+Eufi that one i left enabled!

Comment: I’m going to try the gigabyte and if it doesn't work I’m probably just gonna stick with Windows 10 :(